# How to call server side non-static c# function from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, function, server-side

I need to call a serverside function(C#) to add rows to a table. If i use a normal button to achieve this i automaticly call a postback, by doing this i lose most of my dynamic data i added to my webpage. I did some research and i thought that the easiest way to achieve my goal, which is to add dynamic data to my webpage without calling a postback(or atleast losing my dynamic data), is to call the serverside function from ajax. However then the function needs to be static and that is not possible.

this is my function:

```
public void onButtonPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContentPlaceHolder Content;
        Content = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("MainContent");

        switch(((Button)sender).ID)
        {
            case "FiscaleAddButton":
                // 1:Naam - 2:Adres - 3:Postcode - 4:Contact - 5:Telefoon - 6:Telefoon - 7:Mail - 8:KvK - 9:BTW - 10:Website
                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    cell.Text = ((TextBox)Content.FindControl("FiscaleUnitTextBox" + i.ToString())).Text;
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }
                FiscaleEenhedenTable.Rows.Add(row);
                break;
        }
    }
```

and this is my button:

```
<asp:Button ID="FiscaleAddButton" runat="server" CommandName="FiAdd" Text="Toevoegen" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="onButtonPress"/>
```

I already tried using AJAX to call a `[WebMethod]` but in order for that to work the method needs to be static.

The AJAX code:

```
function callButtonMethod() {     
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'KlantToevoegen.aspx/onButtonPress',
           data: "",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (msg) {
               $("#ContentWrapper").html("success");
           },
           error: function (e) {
               $("#ContentWrapper").html("Something Wrong.");
           }
       });
   }
```

if you have anymore question just ask them in the comments. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void onButtonPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        KlantToevoegen page = getInstance();
        ContentPlaceHolder Content;
        Content = (ContentPlaceHolder)page.Master.FindControl("MainContent");

        switch(((Button)sender).ID)
        {
            case "FiscaleAddButton":
                // 1:Naam - 2:Adres - 3:Postcode - 4:Contact - 5:Telefoon - 6:Telefoon - 7:Mail - 8:KvK - 9:BTW - 10:Website
                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    cell.Text = ((TextBox)Content.FindControl("FiscaleUnitTextBox" + i.ToString())).Text;
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }
                page.FiscaleEenhedenTable.Rows.Add(row);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code that's using `[WebMethod]`

Comment: @Kyojimaru it was the same function, i only removed it cause it wasnt working for me. I also made an static instance of my page to call my controls in a static function. but i will add the code so you can see

Comment: @shariqueansari what does this do? and how will this help me. Your comment is not really helpfull in providing information

Comment: Is it all of your code? I see this code doesn't read any thing from DB or other logical code which is mandatory to be run on server. If you merely want to add new row to a table, you can consider using Javascript or Jquery without a server call. If not then ignore my comment.

Comment: @LifeofMadness, I think you need to use the `AJAX call` to the server to get the value that you want to add into the table (the `Text` from `FiscaleUnitTextBox`), then when `AJAX success` is called, add the returned value to the table using `JavaScript`

Comment: @Kyojimaru i think that might be the best way to solve my problem.

Comment: @aSharma once the user has added all the rows he wants all the rows will be put in a DB.

Comment: @LifeofMadness in that case ignore my comment.

Comment: @LifeofMadness, aSharma way can be used too to save the time you connect to the `Server`. Add the item using `JavaScript`, then when user click `Finish` or anything else, use the `AJAX` to send all the added item to the `server`, then save it in the `DB`.